# properly exiting custom modal dialog in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, modal-dialog, toolbar

My application has a custom dialog box that enables the user to set options on creating a new document. The main window has a toolbar, and even after dismissing the dialog, the toolbar buttons don't return to an active state. I've seen `if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:`
to get the return value, but is there something else that enables the buttons again? Just sending `dialog.Destroy()` doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a "fileDialog" and a "dialog" object open, then you probably need to Destroy them both. If you set the toolbar buttons into a Disabled state, you'll want to Enable them after you dismiss the dialogs.